# Bitbucket / Git LFS error: "Write access is required for uploading LFS objects"

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

First of all, Google tells me:

```
No results found for "Write access is required for uploading LFS objects".
```

Usually that's not a good sign.

---

I have a repository in Bitbucket that has previously worked just fine. The repo uses Git LFS to store some large files, and today I tried to update these large files.

Don't know if it's important, but I'm actually trying to push to a new branch:

```
git push --set-upstream origin my-branch-name
```

However, Git is telling me there's something wrong:

```
Git LFS: (0 of 130 files) 0 B / 261.71 MB
Write access is required for uploading LFS objects
Write access is required for uploading LFS objects
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/reunanen/opencv-binaries-vs'
```

I can push non-LFS changes, and I do have LFS enabled in Bitbucket. Previously everything worked just fine – last time updated these files about one month ago. Also checking out these large files worked today.

Any suggestions I can try? Am I doing something wrong, or should I file a bug [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by [this Bitbucket issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/13963/).

Comment: Downgrading to Git-LFS 1.5.5 didn't help, but changing the authentication method from HTTPS to SSH did.